# How can I get data to jtable from DB like this

Tags: java, database

I want to get data from DB to jtable. I'm not ask the normal way. That meant I send some data to DB. think like this. By invoice i send so many data to Db.. the end of the day I want to search item sale.. think a sale item called 'apple' sold for 4 times.

```
0.item   item code      qty
1.apple   20             5
2.apple   20            20
3.apple   20            23
4.apple   20             7
```

They are in the Db.But I want only

```
0.item   item code      qty
1.apple   20             55
```

The summary of sale items of the day.

Comment: So, write a SQL statement that `select`s just the columns you're interested and may be take a look at the `sum` functionality of SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you should be able to do this with a SQL statement, something like...

```
select item, item_code, sum(qty) as qty from item_table_name where item = 'apple`
```

(ps- It's being a very long time since I wrote SQL ;))

What you really need is some kind of good SQL tutorial.  Try taking a look at [SQL Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/) and [SQLCourse](http://www.sqlcourse.com/index.html)

As Burleigh Bear has suggested

> Rather than `item = 'apple'` you want `group by 'item code'` since all
>   the items have different names

This, of course, assumes you want to summarise each item group, but it worth noting none the less

Comment: oh I got it now.. Thank you Mr.MadProgrammer.. I'll see

Comment: Beware, it's being many years since I had to write SQL, so while I'm reasonably confident on the idea, the implementation may take some tweaking

Comment: Actually I didn't imagine sum(qty) directlty use to search query..thanks alot.. I'll go through it and say the result soon sir..thank you

Comment: +1 for the `sum` pretty good for someone who hasn't written sql in years. Guess it's like riding a bike :)

Comment: @peeskillet I'd say its more like a really bad date, no matter how much you want to forget it...

Comment: Not enough difference to warrant a new answer, but I'd probably say that rather than item = 'apple' you want "group by 'item code'" since all the items have different naems

Comment: @peeskillet huh haaa... :D its true and his answer solved my problem

Comment: @BurleighBear oh yes.. Thank you Mr.Burleigh. Thanks all of you again :D